# Relative paths in Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Given the configuration below for : Nginx, Uwsgi and Flask.

If I move the Flask application from /test/ to production I must update the Nginx configuration, and preferably only that configuration. So a solution would by if the Flask @app.route('/test/') would be relative, so in a non existing syntax: @app.route('[root]'). I can't find a way to accomplish this. That being said, I presume there 'is' a way because if I must alter all the paths in Flask seems so impracticable.

Nginx:

```
location /test/ {
    uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.01:3031;
    include         uwsgi_params;
}
```

Uwsgi:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file myflaskapp.py --callable app --proces$
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test/')
def index():
    return "<span style='color:red'>I am app 1</span>"
```

I'm trying to accomplish to move my application to any sub-path of the domain (site.com/apps, site.com/congres/, and so forth) and only to update the NGINX configuration.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to accomplish? If you want to have a 'test' version of you website, I would advice to use a subdomain, like test.myapp.com.

Comment: @rednaw, good point, I've expanded the question with what I'm trying to accomplish (see last sentence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably thinking of `@app.route('/')`. The route URL appears to be absolute, but it is actually relative to the root URL of your application.

This is actually covered in [Flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/). You only specify the URL to bind your application to in the nginx configuration; Flask should be able to detect this location from the WSGI environment and build its routes accordingly.

Comment: I'm gonna check that this afternoon - if so, you'll have the salt and pepper ready since I'm gonna eat my shoes... fingers crossed...